# Batch file FOR/f expansion

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variable-expansion

I have a file (`directories.txt`) with directory names, each on a single line and I like to expand the line

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\My Documents
```

In my script to the real user name running the script. However the echo comes out exactly the same as the line and `%USERNAME%` does not expand.

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%X IN (directories.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%X
)
```

The echo shows "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\My Documents" instead of C:\Documents and Settings\ **janco** \My Documents

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do this using variable substitution:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%X IN (directories.txt) DO (
    SET DIR=%%X
    ECHO !DIR:%%USERNAME%%=%USERNAME%!
)
```