# User authentication from batch file

Tags: mysql, windows, authentication, batch-file

How can I authenticate a valid user already registered on mysql automatically ? (Can be a batchscript, or vbs or anything that run automatically from windows) and if the user exist and the password is correct, call another batch ?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking.  Do you mean you want to see if a specific username/password combination is a valid mysql user?  Or do you have a users table that your application is using?

Comment: Assuming that you can write the query, the parsing is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746475/dos-windows-batch-help-in-setting-a-variable-from-command-output

Answer (score 1):

You could login with the command line client like so

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"exit" && SET validlogin=true || SET validlogin=false
IF %validlogin% == true (ECHO run batch here) ELSE (ECHO don't run batch)
```

Some dos guru could probably do better