# batch script for windows setting variable value

Tags: batch-file

This part of script is not setting value for variable `creationYear`.

```
set creationYear=dir/T:C %%i | cut -c 7-10

echo %creationYear%
```

Showing ECHO is off, there is `@ECHO OFF` at start.

Comment: If this part of your batch code is inside a __for__ loop or __if__ condition, you need to use delayed environment variable expansion. Open a command prompt window, execute there `set /?` and read the help pages output now. On Stack Overflow search with `[batch-file] delayed expansion` and you will find thousands of questions and answers.

Comment: yes it is in for loop i replaced variable with /creationYear and echo with !creationYear! still not working

Comment: And you can't assign output of a command to an environment variable with the method you tried here. You need a __for__ loop for this task. To get help on command __for__, open a command prompt window, execute there `for /?` and read the help pages output now. Of course on Stack Overflow there are thousands of questions and answers demonstrating how to assign output of a command to an environment variable using __for__.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch help in setting a variable from command output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746475/windows-batch-help-in-setting-a-variable-from-command-output) and [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file).

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir/T:C %%i ^| cut -c 7-10') do (
 set "creationYear=%%#" 
)
echo %creationYear%
```

despite you can get the creation date without external tools like `cut`