# read a file line by line and save it in variable batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following .txt file:

```
Marco
Paolo
Antonio
```

I want to read it line-by-line, and for each line I want to assign a .txt line value to a variable. Supposing my variable is `name`, the flow is:

- Read first line from file
- Assign `name` = "Marco"
- Do some tasks with `name`, let sat `set first= %name%`
- Read second line from file
- Assign `name` = "Paolo"
  How do I do it?

Comment: From command line read the output of `for /?` (look for the `for /f` syntax to process files) and `set /?`, `setlocal /?` (read about `delayed expansion`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch help in setting a variable from command output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746475/windows-batch-help-in-setting-a-variable-from-command-output). Read Joey's answer.

Comment: See my answer: stackoverflow.com/a/74947553/8353248

Answer (score 2):

This will read a file into an array and assign each line into a variable and display them

```dos
@echo off
set "File2Read=file.txt"
If Not Exist "%File2Read%" (Goto :Error)
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo "Var%%i" is assigned to ==^> "!Line[%%i]!"
)
pause>nul
Exit
::***************************************************
:Error
cls & Color 4C
echo(
echo   The file "%File2Read%" dos not exist !
Pause>nul
exit /b
::***************************************************
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without array?

Comment: @FazleRabbi Why this solution does not work for you ? What's your aim ? explain more your purpose ! or edit your question and post the whole code !

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74947553/8353248

Answer (score 0):

*I think this answers your question.*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "somefile=somefile.txt"
if not exist %somefile% (
    echo File '%somefile%' does not exist^^!
    goto :eof
)
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%somefile%) do (
    set "name=%%i"
    set "first=!name!"
    echo !first!
)
```